# Weird VerticalPanel bug?

Tags: gwt

Hi I am quite unsure if the spacing on top of the VerticalPanel widget in my app is a bug or not.

For simplicity, I have this kind of code:

```
public class MainWidget extends Composite {
    private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    public MainWidget() {
        mainPanel.add(new Button("Test button"));
        initWidget(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

When run, the rendered view has this spacing on top of the widget inside the VerticalPanel, about the same height of the button, but not exactly that.

However, if I just put `initWidget(new Button("Test));` the view is rendered properly which the spacing is gone and that the button fits exactly on the top-left of the browser's client area.

I've been struggling to fix this, I have tried DockPanel also but the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any CSS styles that are relevant with this issue? VerticalPanel's are <table>'s, so make sure that you don't have any CSS styling for tables (padding / margins) that may be causing this. I can't reproduce the problem locally on my machine.

Comment: I am not sure if its CSS issue, because other part of the application which uses the same VerticalPanel behaves well. It seems that the spacing is about the same size of the browser scrollbar.

Comment: use firebug to see what is going wrong

Comment: @Zoltan Balazs, I installed Firefox3 to run in debug mode, and the rendering is quite ok, no spacing or undefined padding. Using chrome I get this problems.

Comment: You can use the chrome developer tools (under the tools menu) to inspect the HTML just like in firebug~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this bug is caused by a GWT framework I included in the project which causes this.